# PhpStorm's "Find" window - How can I make the regex checkbox visible by default?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

[image: Regex checkbox hidden]

[image: Regex checkbox visible on mouseover]

As highlighted by the screenshots above, the regex checkbox of PhpStorm's find window is no longer visible by default. This is annoying, because I cannot always see, whether a regular expression is narrowing my search or not. I already googled for a solution, but I cannot seem to find one.

Does anybody of you know how to "fix" this?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Edit: In case you need to know, I am working on a Mac.

Comment: It's a bug in 2018.1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188790 -- says fixed ... but target version is only 2018.2. Try asking there if the fix will be included in 2018.1.3 or so ...

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 2018.1.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188790 -- ticket status says fixed ... but target version is only 2018.2.

Try asking there if the fix will be included in 2018.1.3 or so .. or will it be in 2018.2 only.